# SVN - managing .htaccess file on various instances

Tags: tortoise-svn

I have a question and need a suggestion. We have to manage .htaccess file on three different instances - dev, qa and prod. Currently we have tortoise configured for scm. The issue we are facing is that .htaccess for dev & qa is different from the prod. At present, we have to manually merge differences from dev .htaccess to prod .htaccess. Is there any alternative way of managing this file without this manual process since it is error prone. Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives:

- Use two branches (DEV+QA and PRO), in which only single file will differ and require merge
- If you use correct tools in order to do correct things, you deploy from repo to different targets not by hand, but using some "release manager", which can get additional task of build&deploy - convert **htaccess-template** into **htaccess for this target**

Comment: Thanks for the info..can u pls give me an example of any such release manager..

Comment: @user178087 - Jenkins, Maven